# How to get client side portlet-id in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I'm using AlloyUI in my liferay portlet.

I want to use my `<input>`'s id in javascript. The problem is that the id of the elements are changed in client side.

For example:
If I set an `<input>`'s Id to "username" it is changed to `_hospital_WAR_hospitalportlet_userName` i.e. `_hospital_WAR_hospitalportlet_` is appended to the Id, where `Hospital` is my portlet name.

How can I get client-side Id so that I can use it in jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string `_hospital_WAR_hospitalportlet_` prepended to the `Id` of the `<input>` is nothing but the portlet-namespace.

This is only prepended to your `<input>`'s `name` & `id` attribute if you use `<aui:input>` tag and the `name` & `id` attributes are not changed if you just use plain-vanilla html `<input>` tag.

But as it is a good practice to use `<aui:input>` you can do the following to get the portlet-namespace in your javascript code:

1. If you are using javascripts inside a JSP i.e. using within `<script> .. </script>` or `<aui:script> .. </aui:script>` then you can use **`<portlet:namespace />`** or **`<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>`** to get the string `_hospital_WAR_hospitalportlet_` inside your javascript, something like.

   ```
   jQuery("#<portlet:namespace />username").val();

   // Or

   jQuery("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>username").val();
   ```
2. But if you are using a `*.js` file then I suggest you pass the namespace as an argument to the javascript function in the `js` file:

   ```
   function changeValues(portletNamespace) { // this function is in a js file
       jQuery("#" + portletNamespace + "username").val("Lets change");
   }
   ```

   calling this function from the JSP:

   ```
   <input type="button" onClick="changeValues('<portlet:namespace />')" />
   ```

Hope this helps. I don't know if there is a way to get the `namespace` or `portletId` directly through some javascript function defined by Liferay. If you get something like that you can post it here and that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Liferay.Portlet.ready(

    /*
    This function gets loaded after each and every portlet on the page.

    portletId: the current portlet's id
    node: the Alloy Node object of the current portlet
    */

    function(portletId, node) {
    }
);
```